# I cant get alert to appear when click function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im struggling to get this alert to appear when click on the .cake's.

```
 <ul class="block-container shorthand">
    <li class="block"><img class="cake" src="http://i.imgur.com/MMRz8fe.gif"></li>
    <li class="block"><img class="cake" src="http://i.imgur.com/vkpuOZ5.png"></li>
    <li class="block"><img class="cake" src="http://i.imgur.com/mD8T7FM.png"></li>
    <li class="block"><img class="turkey" src="http://i.imgur.com/Sxj6zq8.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/X5l9hAs.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/Sxj6zq8.png'" /></a></li>
</ul>

     .block-container {
  padding: 60px 70px 70px 70px;
  list-style: none;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.shorthand { 
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.block {
  background: #d31c1c;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 281px;
  height: 281px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.cake {
  max-width: 281px;
}
.turkey {
  max-width: 281px;
}

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cake").click(function(){
        alert("You're into your cake, huh?!");
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/mentionbenjamin/pen/wzkGoy

Tried for an hour and just going in circles.

Thank you stackoverflow, i will pay back to the community once i know what im doing!!

Comment: edited, thank you for the comment.

Comment: Good deal. Next time, though, again, please use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to create a **runnable** on-site example of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not included the Jquery file at all. You need to include the Jquery file for your custom and other jquery plugins to work.

Add this tag into your HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Also you can download the Jquery file and have it in your local project folder and point to that file, The above one is pointing to CDN and works only when you have internet (as it has to be downloaded from the cloud).

Your modified [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgYzyJ)

Comment: thanks, but I've got the tag in the top of my source already.. still not working?

Comment: @wezyourboat can you create a JSFiddle to reproduce the issue with all your code? With the codepen  you gave that was the fix, sorry this didnt help you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzzuu2bx/ the fiddle is working which is peculiar as its not working for me in my browser, confusing one for me!

Comment: @wezyourboat that simply means there are other issues in the page, Do you see any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
 $(".cake").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
         alert(' Your message');
      });
});
})
```

Comment: Please explain your response. No just a source code

Comment: $(".cake") will give all the three img elements. To bind click event,we have to loop through all the elements with class cake. It should work, please let me know if it's working or not.